# Experience Manager Image editing from External DAM system

Tags: 2013, experience-manager

I may sound vague in asking this question but I am using XPM and my tridion pages are referring images which are lying in an External DAM system (Not SDL Media Manager). Is it possible to change those images in-line in XPM? Also, what the experts here suggest for this scenario where I have to do the in-line editing for all the content for page but the image is appearing from a DAM system?

Further, if I implement ECL to integrate with this DAM, will it then be possible to inline edit in XPM the same way we do for SDL Tridion Multimedia Components

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depend on your integration with your DAM system, when using ECL, you can implement editing and saving of the asset via your ECL provider (and the items are basciallly Multimedia Components, so you can swap them out for others etc. as you normally would). Those options will also be exposed to XPM. This mostly means you will be editing or uploading the item via XPM in the external system, through a popup/iframe window. If you are using SAML token authentication for your ECL provider, then it would appear seamless as no additional login is required.

If you take a look at my example [Flickr ECL provider](https://code.google.com/p/sdl-tridion-world/source/browse/#svn/Flickr%20ECL%20Provider/trunk), then you will see how I didn't bother with SAML tokens there, but still provided the upload and editing URLs. So a separate login to Flickr is needed, but you don't need to open up a new browser window yourself, you can reach all directly from the ECL item.

Comment: Thanks Bart. Once I have them changed in XPM as per your approach, is there way to update them back in DAM?

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge with ECL, It does not provide interface/UI to upload the item to your external dam system directly, but you can provide custom interface.

for more information you can refer following API method and other

> IContentLibraryContext.IContentLibraryContext..GetUploadMultimediaItemsUrl