# Unable to Search image in the external DAM from Experience Manager

Tags: experience-manager, ecl

In my project we have integrated the External DAM to SDL tridion.
Now we are able to made the changes on the Pages from Experience Manager. but we are not able to search the asset on the Experience Manager while editing the image. As whenever we select the folder/image from ECL on the left hand side on XPM  "Edit Multimedia Link" appear as disabled.

Does anyone know why this might happen?

Comment: helpful link:http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/5630/experience-manager-image-editing-from-external-dam-system